# firestore vue.js: auth() is not a function

Tags: firebase, vuejs2, firebase-authentication, vuefire

I have a firebase config file like this:

```
import { firebase } from "@firebase/app";
import "@firebase/firestore";

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "myKey",
    authDomain: "myDomain",
    databaseURL: "myURL",
    projectId: "myProject",
    storageBucket: "myBucket",
    messagingSenderId: "999999999"
});

export const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
export const firebaseApp = firebaseApp;
```

I am trying to authenticate a user but keep getting firebaseApp.auth() is not a function.

```
let me = db.collection('staff').where('email', '==', this.current_user.email)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
           this.fbUser = doc.id;
           let email = doc.data().email;
           let pw = doc.data().key;

           firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
              if (user) {
                 //console.log('Already authenticated.');
              } else {
                 firebaseApp.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pw)
                    .then(liu => {
                        //console.log('Logged in', liu.uid);
                        let uid = liu.uid;
                        this.$localStorage.set('fbId',this.fbUser, 0);
                        this.$localStorage.set('fbAuthId', uid, 0);
                        me.update({
                           is_active: true
                        });
                  });
              } // end if
          });
      });
```

Don't I have to configure the app? There's no auth functionality in @firebase.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I believe `auth()` is a method of your `firebase` module rather than your app instance. Have you tried accessing it via `firebase.auth()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add the `auth` Firebase service in your initialization, as follows:

```
import { firebase } from "@firebase/app";
import "@firebase/firestore";
import "@firebase/auth";  // <- NEW

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "myKey",
    authDomain: "myDomain",
    databaseURL: "myURL",
    projectId: "myProject",
    storageBucket: "myBucket",
    messagingSenderId: "999999999"
});

export const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
export const auth = firebaseApp.auth();  // <- NEW
export const firebaseApp = firebaseApp;
```

Then, in your component, you do:

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {})
```

and

```
auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pw)
```